# how to back trace in android native code

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, native-code

My Apk is receiving a sig_stop at epoll_wait. I am unable to figure out the  part of code that is calling this. I know this is a part of libc.It tells me the line number for this epoll_wait . when I tried the tool addr2line , not much luck .

```
 ./toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-   addr2line -C -f -e ~/SoxPlayer/obj/local/armeabi/libc.so  0xafd0c75c
??
??:0
```

This is what I get ..
I want to know what part in my code is forking the thread 1 which calls the epoll_wait.

```
    Thread [1] (Suspended: Signal 'SIGSTOP' received. Description: Stopped (signal).)   
3 epoll_wait()  0xafd0c75c  
2 <symbol is not available> 0xa8125706  
1 <symbol is not available> 0xa8125706
```

Not much information here.
gdb will also provide the same information. ndk-stack tool wont help as I dont have the the kind of sigev fault or app crash which is needed for such a tool. My apk is waiting for the signal , event in my code. but what tool can I use to get who is calling epoll_wait in my code. I am able to see what is happening in my code but not able to pinpoint where exactly this epoll_wait gets called. Need advice about a tool I can use to figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried running it under gdb? gdb will break when the signal is received and you can inspect what the other threads are doing...